# Laravel 5.2 high CPU usage

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

So i have following configurations on my local server

```
Ram: 8gb
Proccessor: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5405 @ 2.00Ghz x 8
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on NV92
Os: Ubuntu 14.04
Apache: 2.4.7
Os type: 64-bit
PHP: 5.6.23
```

[image: Just look at this nasty CPU usage.]

This CPU usage is for laravel-5.2 fresh setup, where i have done no more line of code then what is provided by laravel `(just one defaut welcome page)`. And if I call this page 1000 times CPU usage is very high. For the post methods it goes even bad, and server stops responding.

***I have tried:*** `php artisan optimize`, but as far as i know in laravel 5.2 composer automatic runs this command after `composer update` so it doesn't make any changes in CPU usage.
Anybody facing this issue? Or this is common in laravel?

**Edit:**
Here is normal CPU usage.
[image: Normal CPU usage without any running apache activity]

Comment: Why are you using 5.2 if you're on a fresh setup? 5.5 is the latest.

Comment: As my app is running on 5.2, i have tried to debug my code as if i have made any nasty coding which causing this issue, but nothing found. So as a debugging process i made fresh installation of Laravel-5.2 and encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `Apache` enabled mod? If not I would recommend enabling Apache mod and Here is How to enable mod Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod setenvif headers deflate filter expires rewrite include
```

Open up a terminal and type the following command. Enter your password when prompted.

```
sudo a2enmod setenvif headers deflate filter expires rewrite include
```

Restart apache by using the following command so the new configuration takes effect.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Yes. Only two `(expires, include)` out of which you mention is not seen under `/etc/apache/mod-enabled` folder. Do you think that two modules really needed?

Comment: In some cases the module is required to process php, for example if we install `apache` and `php 7` then we create a `php` file in **/var/www/html** with the contents **phpinfo()** then the out is not the result of **phpinfo ()** but only text **phpinfo()** because apache does not load ``php`` inside it's modules, and I've experienced a long loading we load a ``php`` file and then I try to **enable** those modules and solve

Comment: Okay. I have tried your suggestion, but it doesn't making any changes. Its still higher and almost same.

Comment: Are you running another app that takes up CPU?

Comment: I have added new image in my question showing normal CPU usage. And i think no other app is using that much CPU.